# How to correctly format For XML path results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have to querys and their purpose is to retrieve all entries that fall in the where clause (which isnt important in this instance) and combines them into a stingle column here called `ActualDropOffDateTimeUTC` however the issue i am having is that i am receiving the correct result with the inclusion of the XML tags.

How to format data so the result is equal to (example):
`2016-11-29T20:56:00 - 2016-11-30T09:27:00`

How I actually recieve the data:
`<ActualDropOffDateTimeUTC>2016-11-29T20:56:00</ActualDropOffDateTimeUTC><ActualDropOffDateTimeUTC>2016-11-30T09:27:00</ActualDropOffDateTimeUTC>`

Below I have two attempts to do this under the column name of `ActualDropOffDateTimeUTC` and `SecondAttempt`

```
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
    ActualDropOffDateTimeUTC
    FROM [dbo].[BookingJourneyLinkedCitySprintJobs]
    WHERE
    BookingReference = BJ.BookingReference AND BookingJourneyReference = BJ.BookingJourneyReference AND IsCurrentRevision = 1
    FOR XML PATH('')
) as ActualDropOffDateTimeUTC,


(
    SELECT
    STUFF(
            (
                SELECT ' ' + ActualDropOffDateTimeUTC
                FROM [dbo].[BookingJourneyLinkedCitySprintJobs]
                WHERE
                BookingReference = BJ.BookingReference AND BookingJourneyReference = BJ.BookingJourneyReference AND IsCurrentRevision = 1
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
                ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'
                ),1,1,''
                )
) AS SecondAttempt
```

ActualDropOffDateTimeUTC Result:
`<ActualDropOffDateTimeUTC>2016-11-29T20:56:00</ActualDropOffDateTimeUTC><ActualDropOffDateTimeUTC>2016-11-30T09:27:00</ActualDropOffDateTimeUTC>`

SecondAttempt result:
`016-11-29T20:56:002016-11-30T09:27:00`

## Desired Output:

`2016-11-29T20:56:00 - 2016-11-30T09:27:00`

Comment: Can you please provide some scripts to create tables with dummy data in so we can test your queries, as we don't have access to your data.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you are trying to do:

```
declare @t table(d nvarchar(100));
insert into @t values('2016-11-29T20:56:00'),('2016-11-30T09:27:00');

select stuff((
                select ' - ' + d
                from @t
                for xml path('')
                )
            ,1,3,'')
```

Source Data:
Row 1: `2016-11-29T20:56:00`
Row 2: `2016-11-30T09:27:00`

Query Output:
`2016-11-29T20:56:00 - 2016-11-30T09:27:00`